# How to access remote and encrypted PDF text without writing to local drive

Tags: python, pdf, encryption, text, decode

I am very new to the coding world and have been stuck on this one problem for 3 days now, searching everywhere for an answer, so any help will be greatly appreciated. I am needing to extract a small amount of text from a url-located Pdf file. I'm using `sessions.get(chart_PDF)` as the driver for locating the URL where `chart_PDF` is the example url below.

Example url is https://www.airservicesaustralia.com/aip/pending/dap/PADGN01-166_09SEP2021.pdf

I know I am able to write it to my local drive but I don't want to do that, I want to be able to do it remotely, since I only need a couple of numbers from it.

I have tried finding the password from the url page for decrypting, couldn't find. I've tried to use `PyPDF2`, `pdfminer` and `pikepdf` (probably not well).

I only need to retrieve two numbers near the bottom of the PDF that can be used for the rest of my code. Please help, even if it is a simple fix, I'm new to all this and need some help. Thanks.

```
from io import BytesIO
from pikepdf import Pdf as PDF
from pdfminer import high_level
chart_PDF = https://www.airservicesaustralia.com/aip/pending/dap/PADGN01-166_09SEP2021.pdf
retrieve = s.get(chart_PDF)
content = retrieve.content

response =urllib.request.urlopen(chart_PDF)
p = BytesIO(content)
p.getbuffer()
check = PDFPage.get_pages(p, check_extractable=False)
extract = high_level.extract_text(p)
```

I'm getting:

**PDFTextExtractionNotAllowedWarning: The PDF <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001B007ABEC20> contains a metadata field indicating that it should not allow text extraction. Ignoring this field and proceeding.warnings.warn(warning_msg, PDFTextExtractionNotAllowedWarning)**

Alternately, if I try this:

```
from pikepdf import Pdf as PDF
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
new_pdf = PDF.new()
with PDF.open(p) as pdf:
    print(len(pdf.pages))
    page1 = pdf.pages[0]
    if PdfFileReader.getIsEncrypted(pdf):
        print(True)
        PdfFileReader.decrypt(page1, password='')
pdf.close()
```

I get:

**line 1987, in decrypt
return self._decrypt(password)
AttributeError: _decrypt**

**UPDATE 3/8/21**
Thank you so much K J! You've seriously been a huge help!

```
from io import BytesIO
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer import high_level

retrieve = s.get(chart_PDF)
content = retrieve.content
bytes = BytesIO(content)
bytes.getbuffer()
PDFPage.get_pages(bytes, check_extractable=False)
extract = high_level.extract_text(bytes, password='') #THIS LINE THROWS ERROR
joined = ''.join(extract)
find_txt = re.findall(r'[(]\d*[-]\d[.]\d[)]', joined)
print(find_txt)
bytes.close()
```

This is now working well and I have been able to pull the numbers that I need (I have basically pulled all numbers from inside brackets off the PDF). I'll sort through that to find which one I need.

Strangely enough, although its giving me what I need, my `extract = high_level.extract_text(bytes, password='')` line still throws the Warning: **(warning_msg, PDFTextExtractionNotAllowedWarning)** which is rather annoying. Not sure how this process works but its still letting the info out.

I can't use `try` `except` or it skips over it. What is the way around this? how can I stop that error coming up?

**FINAL UPDATE**

I got around the warning and it works well now.

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    extract = high_level.extract_text(bytes)
```

Cheers fellas for putting up with my ignorance, you've helped so much.

Comment: You can't operate on the remote file - after requesting it from the server the bytes are in your machine.  However you could load the bytes into an [in-memory buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) and operate on them there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have edited my question to include what I'm trying using buffers.  it's most definitely encoded.

Comment: Once you have loaded the pdf data into a buffer you need to pass it to something - perhaps one of the Python PDF packages that you mentioned to be parsed.  Usually the function will state that it accepts a "file-like object" which means the buffer will be acceptable.  Note that PDF is not a text format, so it can't be decoded: the bytes must be parsed by something that understands the PDF file format.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I’ll keep trying and let you know if I get anything.

Comment: I couldn’t figure Mutool out :(. I tried and searched about it. I guess it’s a command line tool and command line I know absolutely nothing at all about except for pip install haha. If there was a way to “cleanup” with Mutool or similar in Python that would be awesome, would get rid of my need for the warning silencer. Converting to HTML and back is a good idea, because each individual chart (like you predicted) shows my desired number in a different location once drawn. I’ll give it a crack mate thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **whole file has to be downloaded** to a device via RAM so the blob as a FILE can be parsed at the very END for **one OR more** %%EOF and the location of **page 0** (it gets converted to 1 or i) it could be ANYWHERE IN THE STREAM,.

THEN you can navigate to other sequential numbered pages in the RANDOM order they are built. Any complaints please contact Adobe.

However it is easiest if it is cached as a physical FILE object. If you dont want that on disk use a **ram drive for your browser**.

Again those two objects at bottom of page one could be **anywhere** mixed into the content of "page" 99's objects, or otherwise. each letter in a PDF can in its extreme be more than one object anywhere in the file. but a good authoring editor would try to keep them as lines by lines. (there is no such PDF thing as a word or paragraph.)

We can Print the file as Plain Text to see how it is composited and although (secured) that is allowed.

[image]

I tried printing from browser with little success but know that can depend on browser system and OS print drivers. Here I have printed the page as text using Acrobat portable, so we can see the sequential offsets of each text block from Left Hand margin JUST LIKE a PDF VIEWER would need to rebuild them.

[image]

**UPDATE**
You said your target is (1380-4.4) to the RIGHT of ALTERNATE but again A PDF has no concept of Left and Right or BEFORE or AFTER so we find IN THIS FILE the variable target is in 2 separate pieces PRIOR to the KNOWN characters which luckily is a complete single block (alternate). Thus here proximity of plain text could well work if the capture is confined to that nearby locality. However there is no guarantee that ALTERNATE would always be a single block.

[image]

It was perhaps not a good Idea To show the way a Printer would be given a stream of sequential data
Here is the way one PDF viewer goes about decrypting the file
[image]

As stated on this occasion the word ALTERNATE is defined as text however the next item is the "3" under "B" which is text as a vector path it is not called a "character" although it looks like one but a numbered glyph from a font table. We do see later that some of those numbers are stored as "text" and for your target it is mixed in with similar text in the same object.

[image]

**Thus you need to call a PDF interpreter** to give you a meaningful translation of all bits and pieces of objects so that you can extract the "right" text.

The easiest way for a "simple" one line target in a complex file is to use MuPDF to first tidy up the file

```
    mutool clean -gggg -D infile.pdf outfile.pdf
```

combined with

```
    PDFTOTXT -layout outfile.pdf outfile.txt
```

or similar to hopefully export that text on a line by line basis, such that you can consistently find your target instantly **before** ! or after ALTERNATE.

N.B Mutool convert to HTML would place the target value in a table entry AFTER the key word, and if the lines are consistent in number that would be a simpler way to find or grep.

Comment: Thank you so much for spending the time to help me. Yeah, I literally only need the (1380-4.4) number field to the right of the ALTERNATE to be drawn from this file. My program will be choosing the PDF chart which will be indirectly decided by the user's input. So my method of extracting said numbers will have to work on any chart, the good thing is that all of the PDF charts have the exact same layout. You're saying it is able to be printed as plain text although secured which is good. I have been trying to get past this problem.

Comment: Thank you, good to know it’s in there somewhere. I was planning (once I can figure out how to extract text) on using Regex.findall to pull everything. I was then going to make it a list so I can grab it via an index pos. I know you’re saying there’s no “positions” within the file, which I get. I just hope the white space equates to nothing when running the findall. Have you got an idea of some code that would be able to grab this text? You can see my attempts above have failed me. Would you build on what I have or start from scratch?

Comment: KJ thank you so much for your help mate. I tried everything you suggested. You are all over it! I've updated my original question.